# Trying to run rails server prints out error with common.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Error here. The command was working fine until randomly it began spitting out this error. I've removed the code I added before this error began and nothing is helping remedy the situation. The lines of code that the error points don't even seem related to my actual code.

```
home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 743: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:70:in `load'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:15:in `bootstrap'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker.rb:18:in `bootstrap'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:37:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
from /home/ec2-user/portfolio/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from config.ru:in `new'
from config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/portfolio/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /home/ec2-user/portfolio/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ec2-user/portfolio/bin/spring:15:in `require'
from /home/ec2-user/portfolio/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you tried stopping your server, running `spring stop`, and then restarting your server?

Comment: @jvillian I'm not using spring and no other server is running

Comment: Hm. Very strange given the line: `from /home/ec2-user/portfolio/bin/spring:15:in '<top (required)>'` and the ~8 lines right above that.

Comment: This is the command I'm using `rvmsudo rails s -b ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 80`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still struggling with this, but I had the exact same problem so I figured I'd answer here for future stragglers.

I had to reinstall node and then rebuild (`npm rebuild node-sass`). I'm pretty sure this happened because some of the files in my node installation were erroneously deleted. This could also happen if you're running an outdated version of Node (https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/192 - apparently before 6.1 Node was incompatible with ES6).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same error when migrated my rails app assets configurations from sprockets to webpack.

Upgrading from Node 5.12 to >6 solved this issue for me.